# Get closest value in an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, math, int, min

```
int [] testArray = new int[3] { 5, 7, 8};

int check = 22;

var nearest = testArray.Min(x => Math.Abs(x - check));

Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(nearest));
```

I have the above code as an attempt to try and get the nearest number in the array closest to the check number, in this case 22.

The thing is that this always returns a positive value because of the Math.Abs but if I remove this the code completely fails. for example if the check number is 10, i want nearest to return -2 and not 2. This way I can just add the nearest value to the check number to get the proper value that's in the array.

I found something similiar upon searching, something called MoreLinq, that suggested using array.MinBy instead, however this method throws an error (says it doesn't exist)... Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the number in the array which is closest to your number or the distance to this number? The title suggests you want 22 to lead to 8 as a result, however your explanation and code seem more like expecting (-)14.

Comment: MoreLinq is an extension of Linq. You can get it from nuget package manager. Check out https://morelinq.github.io/

Comment: @wkl the idea is to get 8, however I was trying to achieve this by first getting the distance and then add it to the initial number to get the one in the array.

Comment: @DavidFarrugia thank you for the explanation. I should have read more carefully...

Comment: @wkl no worries :) thanks for your help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would propose first order on min and take the first value. It's your nearest value and you could do with it what you want. For example calculate `nearest-check`

```
int[] testArray = new int[3] { 5, 7, 8 };

int check = 22;

var nearest = testArray.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x - check)).First();

Debug.Print(Convert.ToString(nearest-check));
```

Comment: Thanks tweeked it a bit and worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Comment: That's elegant :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the source array is guaranteed to be sorted, you can use [Array.BinarySearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb(v=vs.110).aspx). I guarantee that it will be faster than any LINQ solution you may find.

```
int[] arr = { 3, 5, 7 };
int idx = Array.BinarySearch(arr, 3);
int closest = idx < 0 ? arr[~idx] : arr[idx];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `testArray.Aggregate((min, next) => Math.Abs(next - check) > Math.Abs(min - check) ? min : next)`. It must be faster, than `OrderBy()`.